# Using rgl package to plot a 2D image from local disk

Tags: image, plot, 2d, rgl

This is probably pretty straightforward but I'm stuck for hours...

I don't a code example but I'll keep it simple.

My app looks into a folder and checks if STL files exist based on a selectizeinput.

Then, it plots the STL without an issue.

However, the amount of STL in the folder is scarce compared to the selectize options.

My goal is to have an if statement that outputs the STL if there an STL file (so far, so good...) and outputs a 2D image (something like 404 file not found).

I looked at rgl documentation and this last part (2D image) is where I can't seem to figure out how to plot it...

Hopefully I was clear and someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Here is an example of code to clarify

```
observe({
    
    req(input$slider1)
    
    # Load filenames in STL folder
    stl_files <- list.files("~www/STL/", pattern = ".stl", full.names = F)
    
    if (is.null(input$slider1)  || length(input$slider1) < 1 || input$slider1 == F || input$slider1 == "$0" || (paste0(input$slider1[1],".stl") %in% stl_files) == F ){ 
    
      output$"3D-plot_1" <- renderRglwidget({
        
     # here I would like to plot a 2D image in case the stl file does not exit and this where I'm stuck.
                
      })
      
    } else {
      
      # Create STL Plot 
      output$"3D-plot_1" <- renderRglwidget({
        
        stl_1 <- readSTL(con = paste0("~www/STL/", input$slider1, ".stl"), ascii = F, plot = F)
        
        stl_centered_1 <- scale(stl_1, center = T, scale = F)
        
        options(rgl.useNULL=TRUE)
        open3d()
        
        rgl::triangles3d(stl_centered_1, aspect = "iso", col = "grey")
        bg3d("black")
        scene1 <- scene3d()
        rglwidget(scene1)
        
      })
    }
  })
```

Comment: We need a code example to show us the context.  You don't need to plot an STL file, just plot something simple, so we know where the image should go.

Comment: Thanks @user2554330 for the reply. I've added some code to clarify.

Comment: Your code isn't usable by anyone else, so I won't post an answer.  But I don't understand why you are trying to use `renderRglwidget()` to post an image:  why not use `renderImage()`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The idea of the code was to be an example, not a working one. Perhaps I misunderstood...my attempts to use renderImage for an stl file were not successful. renderRGLwidget() works fine for the 3D stl file. The issue I'm having is that I need to use renderRGLwidget for the STL but in case there isn't a STL file I would like to render a 2D image. However, this becomes an issue on UI side since I would need an if statement on that side as well to choose between rglwidgetOutput for the STL or imageOutput or for the 2D image. Hopefully this was clear.

Comment: If you post a working example, then people can test their suggestions.  It saves a lot of time for everyone.